# How should a DLL register a window class to be used by the EXE program?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, registering

How can I register a window class in my DLL so that the window class can be used in the EXE program?

From [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassa):

> hInstance (Type: HINSTANCE): A handle to the instance that contains the window procedure for the class.

And also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#instance-handle):

> The system passes an instance handle to the entry-point function of each executable (see WinMain) and .dll (see DllMain). The executable or .dll assigns this instance handle to the class by copying it to the hInstance member of the WNDCLASSEX structure.

I should set the hInstance member of WNDCLASS to my DLL instance handle.

But according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindoww)

> The class name can be any name registered with RegisterClass or RegisterClassEx, provided that the module that registers the class is also the module that creates the window.

So because my DLL registers the window class (regardless of the value of hInstance member of WNDCLASS?) only my own DLL can create a window from that window class?

So how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Unless I misunderstand how things work, the cited section from the `CreateWindowW` documentation seems to be wrong. If it were correct, then there would be no reason to have `CreateWindowW` take an `hInstance` parameter. Have a look at [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873) and see if there is a different conclusion I'm not seeing.

Comment: @IInspectable: I think "If you pass the CS_GLOBALCLASS flag when registering the class, then the window manager will ignore the instance handle when looking for your class." is relevant. Perhaps I should be using CS_GLOBALCLASS  when registering the class.

Comment: Indeed I think that is the solution: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#application-global-classes) says: "An application global class is a window class registered by an executable or DLL that is available to all other modules in the process. For example, your .dll can call the RegisterClassEx function to register a window class that defines a custom control as an application global class so that a process that loads the .dll can create instances of the custom control."

Comment: To my understanding, the `CS_GLOBALCLASS` class style is only relevant if the caller of `CreateWindowExW` is outside your control. The example given is the dialog manager that will internally create the child windows, but doesn't have a way of knowing, which module registered the window classes. Blindly applying the `CS_GLOBALCLASS` will have you run into the issue of class name collisions.

Comment: @IInspectable: I think CreateWindowW documentation misses the fact that the cited section only applies to classes registered without CS_GLOBALCLASS. CS_GLOBALCLASS indeed creates a problem of possible name collision but that seems to be the price.

Comment: This [link](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/windows-programming/166207-registerclass-unregisterclass-dll.html) seems to offer a different solution in which the DLL passes the EXE instance handle to the RegisterClass. Cited section of documentation however doesn't allow this, and the link that you posted also says: "A common mistake is to pass the HINSTANCE of some other module (typically, the primary executable) when registering a window class."

Comment: The more I read the documentation the more I'm inclined to believe that it's written under the assumption that client code doesn't know the `HMODULE` of the DLL that registered the window class. Things should just work if a DLL registers a local class, and client code passes the correct `hInstance` into the `CreateWindowExW` call. I'll do some testing if I can free up enough disk space...

Comment: On the other hand, if you are writing a library and cannot expect clients to (easily) gain access to the `HMODULE` of your implementation, there's nothing inherently wrong with using the `CS_GLOBALCLASS` class style. You can avoid the name collision issue by using the string representation of a GUID for the class name. The class name can be communicated to clients by way of the supporting header file.

Comment: @IInspectable: `CS_GLOBALCLASS` seems to be the only documented method. Using string representation of a GUID seems a good solution to avoid name collision. (I accept this as an answer if you post it) Apart from the documented method, these two may also work: 1) Both RegisterClass (in DLL) and CreateWindow (in EXE) pass the instance handle of the EXE. In the link I posted, this is described to be common among open source projects. But the more-reliable link that you posted calls this a common mistake. 2) Both RegisterClass (in DLL) and CreateWindow (in EXE) pass the instance handle of the DLL.

Comment: [When should I use CS_GLOBALCLASS?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230310-00/?p=107926)

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Well then the alternative method 2 (in my previous comment) proposed by IInspectable works and is the preferred method. (As the link says: "Now, even if you register all your classes to your own `HINSTANCE`, other people can still create it if they have both the instance handle and the class name. You can document the class name in your library’s header file, and people can create it via `Create­Window`:", and then gives an example.) Also the cited section of `CreateWindowW` seems to be wrong. (For classes with or without `CS_GLOBALCLASS`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual answer is to have a function in your DLL that registers the window classes, just as InitCommonControls from Comctl32.dll does for the common controls. That function will use the HINSTANCE passed to the library's DllMain as the HINSTANCE in WNDCLASS/WNDCLASSEX.

When the loading application wishes to create a window it will use the HINSTANCE returned by LoadLibrary as the HINSTANCE parameter to CreateWindow/CreateWindowEx. It is assumed that the class name is already shared between the application and library code (again just as the control names are shared between Comctl32.dll and any using code).

Comment: The problem comes when you want to use a window class from a DLL in a dialog created from a resource template.

Comment: Apparently, this is the standard way of doing it when we can control the HINSTANCE parameter of CreateWindow call. Although it is not quite logical, I think even passing HINSTANCE of the EXE to both the RegisterClass call and the CreatWindow call will work. What Raymond Chen is calling a mistake is probably passing HINSTANCE of the EXE to RegisterClass call but passing HINSTANCE of the DLL to CreateWindow call. Also the cited section of CreateWindowW documentation can be interpreted in two ways; only one of which is correct. The correct interpretation is easier to see in this extended version:

Comment: "The class name can be any name registered with RegisterClass(Ex), provided that the module that registers the class is also the module that creates the window. The class name can be any name registered with RegisterClass(Ex) combined with CS_GLOBALCLASS. The class name can't be a name registered with RegisterClass(Ex) without CS_GLOBALCLASS, if the module that registers the class is not the module that creates the window." (In all of which 'module that registers the class' and 'module that creates the window' refers to HINSTANCE passed to RegisterClass(Ex) and CreateWindow respectively)